# Session variables skipping multiple requests

Tags: mule, esb

I understand that session variables in Mule ESB can be shared between different flows of the same request, but... How can I make a variable visible to multiple requests?
It is a variable, so it would change depending on the data the flow receive.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the registry or the object store. However, how would you handle synchronization between different requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the new mule 3.4 cache scope to store/cache objects, alternatively you can  use the Mule Objectstore to save the session value as key and object. This
can be **in-memory** or **persistent**

```
<objectstore:retrieve key="mykey" defaultValue-ref="myvalue"/>
```